# Out of band socket data in Windows Store apps

Tags: sockets, microsoft-metro, telnet, windows-store, out-of-band

I have been working on a telnet/SSH app for the Windows Store and the telnet app has been receiving OOB data on its socket but I can't see it inside the app. I know this because the desktop version of the app is receiving OOB data. I also confirmed that the receive buffer in the Windows Store version is missing the one OOB data byte. In Wireshark I have confirmed that the OOB data is being received by the computer so its just not being forwarded to my app. I know in WinSock you need to set a special parameter to receive OOB data inline but I cannot find any such option for a Windows Store app. Does anyone know of a way to get this OOB data?

Another option would be to tell the telnet server to stop sending the OOB data. Is there to tell it to stop sending it?

For reference, the OOB data is being sent when pressing Ctrl+C. The OOB data byte is 0xFF and is the first byte sent by the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this functionality is not implemented in WinRT. Marking as answered.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05a26a4b-e0db-4fed-b5d0-b67a2d9e2b1c/out-of-band-data-using-windowsnetworkingsockets?forum=winappswithnativecode